# How resource close statement works in Java 7 internally?

Tags: java, java-7, try-with-resources, autocloseable

Java 7 features has **autoclose** of resource and **multi-catch statement**, but how it works **internally** in both cases?

For example

```
// Try with resource
public void testTryWithResourcesStatement() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("java7.txt")) {
        System.out.println(in.read());
    }
}
```

Here there is no need for *finally*. But how it works internally? How JVM closes it internally?

Comment: why it is nagative voted can any body explain ? what's wrong with it

Comment: Prior research. Have you tried asking a search engine. And hint: this is what we call syntax sugar. It is not the JVM but the compiler doing the magic.

Comment: This question is pretty broad - it sounds like you're asking someone to explain the implementation details of something deep in the JVM/compiler.

Comment: You should take a look at the **bytecode** in general such things will be automatically converted for compatibility and generate the exact same code internally. So *try-with-resources* probably gets converted to the same code than the usual *try-catch-finally and close* stuff.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can you please share any resource related to this. will appreciate.

Comment: And just another hint : google for AutoClosable. As said: use a search engine. You can do that! Go and try!

Comment: Here is an article explaining what happens under the hood (just a quick google search): https://www.sourceclear.com/blog/Exception-Handling-with-Try-with-Resources-Statement-in-Java-7/